# Spark streaming LOCAL run doesn't start when doing foreachbatch or flatMapGroupWithState

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm facing a strange issue, I'm doing some tests about structured streaming, to do that I'm creating some main executed in LOCAL mode, everything was working fine until I tested *flatMapGroupsWithState*, when using arbitraryStatefulAggregation, the job won't do any task.

My code is just a POC, it will mantaing a rolling count on the keys:

```
  case class Type4(nome: String, ts: Timestamp, num: Int)

  
  def eventTimeoutAgg(ds: Dataset[Type4]): Dataset[(String, Int)] = {

    def mappingFunction(key: String, iter: Iterator[Type4], state: GroupState[Int]): Iterator[(String, Int)] = {
      if (state.hasTimedOut) {
        state.remove()
      }
      var sum = state.getOption.getOrElse(0)
      val list = iter.toList
      list.foreach { v =>
        sum += v.num
      }
      state.update(sum)
      state.setTimeoutTimestamp(list.map(_.ts.getTime).max, "30 minutes")
      Iterator((key, sum))
    }

    ds.withWatermark("ts", "1 minutes")
      .groupByKey(_.nome)
      .flatMapGroupsWithState(OutputMode.Append(), GroupStateTimeout.EventTimeTimeout())(mappingFunction)
  }
   import spark.implicits._

    val schema = StructType(
      Seq(
        StructField("nome", StringType, nullable = false),
        StructField("ts", StringType, nullable = false)
      )
    )
    // Reading csv files
    val df = spark.readStream.schema(schema).options(Map("header" -> "false")).csv("/user/svc_va-dev/dbelvedere/data/*").withColumn("ts", to_timestamp($"ts", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).withColumn("num", lit(1)).asInstanceOf[DataFrame]
      

  val ds = df.as[Type4]
  eventTimeoutAgg(ds).writeStream
  .format("console")
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
  .start
  .awaitTermination
```

This is working fine on a spark shell on a real cluster, only on LOCAL mode I'm facing, the path from which I'm reading csv files is populated at start, so from the first batch it should retrieve data, even adding other csv to the folder after job start, it doesn't even start to instantiate any job (verified from spark UI).

**the same thing is happening for foreachBatch streamWriter sink, all other usecases like join and group by are working fine**

Attaching also final process logs, at TRACE level

```
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Starting job: start at ArbitraryStateful.scala:33
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: eagerlyComputePartitionsForRddAndAncestors for RDD 9 took 0,001402 seconds
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Merging stage rdd profiles: Set()
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Merging stage rdd profiles: Set()
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 5 (start at ArbitraryStateful.scala:33) as input to shuffle 0
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (start at ArbitraryStateful.scala:33) with 2 output partitions
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (start at ArbitraryStateful.scala:33)
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: submitStage(ResultStage 1 (name=start at ArbitraryStateful.scala:33;jobs=0))
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: missing: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: submitStage(ShuffleMapStage 0 (name=start at ArbitraryStateful.scala:33;jobs=0))
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: missing: List()
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at start at ArbitraryStateful.scala:33), which has no missing parents
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: submitMissingTasks(ShuffleMapStage 0)
23/10/11 17:52:09 TRACE org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager: Task -1024 trying to put broadcast_2
23/10/11 17:52:09 TRACE org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager: Task -1024 trying to acquire write lock for broadcast_2
23/10/11 17:52:09 TRACE org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager: Task -1024 acquired write lock for broadcast_2
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 33.2 KiB, free 1984.6 MiB)
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager: Put block broadcast_2 locally took 1 ms
23/10/11 17:52:09 TRACE org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager: Task -1024 releasing lock for broadcast_2
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager: Putting block broadcast_2 without replication took 1 ms
23/10/11 17:52:09 TRACE org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager: Task -1024 trying to put broadcast_2_piece0
23/10/11 17:52:09 TRACE org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager: Task -1024 trying to acquire write lock for broadcast_2_piece0
23/10/11 17:52:09 TRACE org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager: Task -1024 acquired write lock for broadcast_2_piece0
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 15.8 KiB, free 1984.6 MiB)
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Updating block info on master broadcast_2_piece0 for BlockManagerId(driver, AGSLPT01216DB.ags.wan, 54408, None)
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on AGSLPT01216DB.ags.wan:54408 (size: 15.8 KiB, free: 1985.3 MiB)
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_2_piece0
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager: Told master about block broadcast_2_piece0
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager: Put block broadcast_2_piece0 locally took 2 ms
23/10/11 17:52:09 TRACE org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager: Task -1024 releasing lock for broadcast_2_piece0
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager: Putting block broadcast_2_piece0 without replication took 2 ms
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1580
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at start at ArbitraryStateful.scala:33) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks resource profile 0
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Epoch for TaskSet 0.0: 0
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Adding pending tasks took 2 ms
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Valid locality levels for TaskSet 0.0: NO_PREF, ANY
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Valid locality levels for TaskSet 0.0: NO_PREF, ANY
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (AGSLPT01216DB.ags.wan, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 8263 bytes) 
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: No tasks for locality level NO_PREF, so moving to locality level ANY
23/10/11 17:52:09 INFO org.apache.spark.executor.Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.executor.ExecutorMetricsPoller: stageTCMP: (0, 0) -> 1
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_2
23/10/11 17:52:09 TRACE org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager: Task 0 trying to acquire read lock for broadcast_2
23/10/11 17:52:09 TRACE org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager: Task 0 acquired read lock for broadcast_2
23/10/11 17:52:09 DEBUG org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_2 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
23/10/11 17:52:10 DEBUG org.apache.spark.executor.ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
23/10/11 17:52:58 TRACE org.apache.spark.HeartbeatReceiver: Checking for hosts with no recent heartbeats in HeartbeatReceiver.
23/10/11 17:53:58 TRACE org.apache.spark.HeartbeatReceiver: Checking for hosts with no recent heartbeats in HeartbeatReceiver.
23/10/11 17:54:58 TRACE org.apache.spark.HeartbeatReceiver: Checking for hosts with no recent heartbeats in HeartbeatReceiver.
```

as you can see it is not advancing